# Segmentation fault from calling a function from an object within an array

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a programming assignment that requires us to use a dynamically allocated two-dimensional char array in-lieu of strings and vectors. I have two classes: Word which holds a pointer to a char array, and WordList which holds a pointer to a Word array.

The segmentation fault comes from this section of code:

```
for(int i=0; i<listLength; i++)
    fout << "Word " << i << (wordList[i])->getWord() << endl;
```

where fout is an ofstream object, wordList is a Word** object, and getWord() is a member function of a Word object. The thing is that I use the same wordList[i]->getWord() syntax in another member function of WordList and get the proper output.

Please let me know if more code is needed to properly diagnose the problem

More code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>  
#include "Word.h"

using namespace std;

class WordList
{
public:
    int listLength_;
    Word** wordList_; 

WordList()
{   
    char blank = ' ';
    char* blankPtr = &blank;
    setListLength(1);
    wordList_ = new Word* [listLength_];
    for(int i=0; i<listLength_; i++)
    {
        wordList_[i] = new Word(blankPtr);
    }
}

void addWord(Word* word, Word** wordList, int n)
{
    Word** wl_temp = new Word* [n+1];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        wl_temp[i] = wordList[i];
    }

    wl_temp[n] = word;
    delete[] wordList;
    setWordList(wl_temp);
    listLength_++;            
    cout << " " << (wordList_[n]->getWord()); //works here 
}

void parse(const char* filename)
{
    ifstream fin(filename);

    char end;
    char* tw;
    while(fin >> end)
    {
        fin.unget();
        fin.get(tw=new char[49], 49, ' ');
        Word* w = new Word(tw);
        addWord(w, getWordList(), getListLength());

        delete w;
        delete[] tw;
    }  
}

void output(const char* outfile)
{
    ofstream fout(outfile);

for(int i=1; i<=listLength_; i++)
        fout << "Word " << i << (wordList_[i])->getWord() << endl; //not here
    fout.close();
}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WordList wordList;

    wordList.parse(argv[1]);
    wordList.output(argv[2]);

    return 1;   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `wordList[i]` is not null? Also, please show how you allocate the array and its members.

Comment: Can you provide more code please?  Ideally a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg positive wordList[i] is not null as I am able to access is from a different function

Comment: Even if it seems to work in another function, some other problem may cause it to not work in the this function. Have you used a debugger to pinpoint this location? Have you checked the variables and pointers involved? If the other function, where it works, is the one where you create the array, maybe it's a local array that you return so it's not valid outside that function? Please create an SSCCE as advised by simonc.

Comment: edited for more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `blankPtr` in the constructor points to a local variable, this pointer will not be valid once the constructor returns. Also, in the `parse` function you delete the pointer to the string, making that pointer invalid as well. Not only that, you actually delete the `Word` object pointer, meaning you have now have an illegal pointer in your array.

Unless you create a copy (not just copy the pointer, but allocate new memory) inside the `Word` constructor, your `Word` objects will contain illegal pointers leading to undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior is tricky, since it can seem to work one time, but not another.

Answer (score 1):

In `WordList::Wordlist`:

```
    wordList_[i] = new Word(blankPtr);
```

You're passing a pointer to a local variable here.

Not only is that a problem in itself, but the "string" isn't zero-terminated.
Regardless of whether `Word` assumed ownership of the object, this will cause undefined behaviour.

If `Word::Word` copies its argument, this is a very roundabout (and wrong) way to write `new Word(" ")`.

In `parse`:

```
    Word* w = new Word(tw);
    addWord(w, getWordList(), getListLength());

    delete w;
```

You added `w` to the word list. Now you're `delete`ing it.
The word list now contains a pointer to released memory.
Dereferencing it also causes undefined behaviour.

```
   delete[] tw;
```

This is only OK if `Word::Word` copies its argument. Otherwise it now holds a pointer you aren't allowed to use for anything.

If you're going to work with hand-rolled allocation and raw pointers, you need to set a very clear policy for which object owns which memory and is responsible for allocating and releasing it.
The best time to do this is before you touch the keyboard.